# How to select data from custom combo box in which select action, robot action is not working reliably using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, sendkeys, awtrobot

```html
String value = “Card77”; // value which i need to select from custom box
initRobot(); // initiate robot globally
driver.findElement(By.classname(“custom-combobox”)).click(); // click custom box
Type.word(value); //type value in the drop to select


 public void initRobot() {
  try {
   variables.robot = new Robot();
  } catch (AWTException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

public class Type {
 public static void word(String str) throws Exception{
  int length = str.length(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
   char character = str.charAt(i);
   Charecter(character);
  }
 }

public static void Charecter(char character) throws AWTException {
  Robot robot = variables.robot;
  
  switch (character) {
  
  case 'a': 
  
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);break;
  
  case 'b': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);break;
  
  case 'c': 
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
  break;
  
  case 'd': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);break;
  
  case 'e': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);break;
  
  case 'f': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);break;
  
  case 'g': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);break;
  
  case 'h': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);break;
  
  case 'i': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);break;
  case 'j': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);break;
  case 'k': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_K);break;
  case 'l': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);break;
  case 'm': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);break;
  case 'n': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);break;
  case 'o': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);break;
  case 'p': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);break;
  case 'q': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);break;
  case 'r': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);break;
  case 's': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);break;
  case 't': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);break;
  case 'u': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);break;
  case 'v': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);break;
  case 'w': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);break;
  case 'x': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);break;
  case 'y': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);break;
  case 'z': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z);break;

  case 'A':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'B':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'C': 
   
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);

  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'D':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'E':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'F':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'G':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'H':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'I':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'J':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_J);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'K':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_K);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'L':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'M':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'N':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'O':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'P':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'Q':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'R':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'S':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'T':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'U':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'V':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'W':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'X':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'Y':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case 'Z':  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case '`': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);break;

  case '0': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);break;

  case '1': 
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);break;

  case '2': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);break;

  case '3': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);break;

  case '4': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_4);break;

  case '5': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);break;

  case '6': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_6);break;

  case '7': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_7);break;

  case '8': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_8);break;

  case '9': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_9);break;

  case '-': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);break;

  case '=': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);break;

  case '~': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case '!': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK);break;

  case '@': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_AT); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_AT);break;

  case '#': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN);break;

  case '$': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOLLAR);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOLLAR);break;

  case '%': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;

  case '^': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX);break;

  case '&': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_AMPERSAND); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_AMPERSAND);break;   
  case '*': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ASTERISK);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ASTERISK);break;
  case '(': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS);break;
  case ')': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS);break;
  case '_': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);break;
  case '+': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);break;
  case '\t': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);break;
  case '\n': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);break;
  case '[': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);break;
  case ']': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);break;
  case '\\': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);break;
  case '{': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);break;
  case '}': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);break;
  case '|': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH);break;
  case ';': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);break;
  case ':': robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON); 
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);break;
  // kept continuing for all charecters
  } 
 }
```

How to select data from the custom combo box, in which select action is not accepting and robot action is often not simulating keyboard actions properly. Tried all possible ways of robot actions, sendkeys, select actions, but none is working effieciently, please help me by suggesting any other alternative to robot actions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woOWx.png)

```
<div class="margb_med">
    <div class="left input_label mandatory">Card Template</div>
    <div class="left input_field">
        <select id="cardTemplate" style="display: none;">
            <option value="" selected="">Select Card</option>
            <option value="75" id="75">Card77</option>
        </select>
        <span class="custom-combobox">
            <input title="" class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
            <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" role="button" title="">
                <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML for this custom dropdown instead of screenshot and also share tried attempt as well..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: You dumped a bunch of code, most of which is irrelevant to the question. Please provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not regular dropdown, in this i am trying to click the element, then the a list will populated, from that i want to select one. I am trying to simulate it by robot action,  but it is working only few times, more times it failing to simulate,

Comment: coming to my code, i am trying to select a value Card77, then I am clicking on the element, simulating all the key board charecters with robot, there is no extra code in that I trimmed completely. please let me know where couldnt understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String card = "Card"+variables.iteration; 
js.executeScript("$('#cardTemplate').siblings('.custom-combobox').find('.ui-autocomplete-input').val('"+card+"')");

Comment: Loads of Thanks for the people who tried to answer me.. regrets for the people who gave me dislikes..